# Next-JS V14.0.2 crashes on deployment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongodb, next.js, vercel

I'm new to NextJs and having issues deploying my NextJs app. I have a test NextJs and MongoDb  fullstack application that I wrote to hone my skills better, it runs fine locally but crashes when I deploy it to vercel and returns two errors in the browser console. I have searched and searched for solutions but still haven't been able to resolve it, Please I need help.

These errors are;

```bash
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sqrt')
    at 155-6322358b00f50a64.js:5:13033
    at 155-6322358b00f50a64.js:5:13083
    at 54519 (155-6322358b00f50a64.js:5:13152)
    at l (webpack-dd3cd49180925084.js:1:152)
    at 44155 (155-6322358b00f50a64.js:1:14447)
    at l (webpack-dd3cd49180925084.js:1:152)
    at 18346 (676-ce2c77460caee114.js:1:36547)
    at l (webpack-dd3cd49180925084.js:1:152)
    at 15931 (page-9c9c707904a0c6d8.js:1:9713)
    at Function.l (webpack-dd3cd49180925084.js:1:152)
```

and

```bash
fd9d1056-614c4d273fc3bb18.js:1 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=423 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at iU (fd9d1056-614c4d273fc3bb18.js:1:117435)
    at o2 (fd9d1056-614c4d273fc3bb18.js:1:94370)
    at fd9d1056-614c4d273fc3bb18.js:1:94192
    at o1 (fd9d1056-614c4d273fc3bb18.js:1:94199)
    at oV (fd9d1056-614c4d273fc3bb18.js:1:91686)
    at oB (fd9d1056-614c4d273fc3bb18.js:1:91111)
    at MessagePort.C (472-f9c643575ba72596.js:1:101500)
iU  @   fd9d1056-614c4d273fc3bb18.js:1
o2  @   fd9d1056-614c4d273fc3bb18.js:1
(anonymous) @   fd9d1056-614c4d273fc3bb18.js:1
o1  @   fd9d1056-614c4d273fc3bb18.js:1
oV  @   fd9d1056-614c4d273fc3bb18.js:1
oB  @   fd9d1056-614c4d273fc3bb18.js:1
C   @   472-f9c643575ba72596.js:1
```

Please I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue

Comment: Whatever is calling `sqrt` is `undefined`, which means you will have to first check that it exists, I tried to search the repo but Git is doing some indexing. It would be better to share code that shows what object is having `sqrt` called on it, and ensuring it is defined from the start

Comment: I didn't use `sqrt` anywhere in my code directly, I suspect it's from a third party library

Comment: Hm interesting, in that case there should be some warnings somewhere in the console when running or installing the packages. I would hazard a guess that some library has been updated or installed and isn't playing nice with the others. You could try deleting the `node_modules/` directory (and potentially also the `package_lock.json` file) and reinstalling the libraries to see if there are any issues when installing, and then which libraries are causing the issue(s)

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to resolve it;

I was using crypto-js library which had issues and I suspect it was the library giving me the `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sqrt')`, So I looked for an alternative library and then also implemented this `Be sure an object is not undefined before accessing any of it's properties.One way to do that is to use an ? operator like textObject?.property.` in everywhere I have a case like it in my codes

I also changed the value of `moduleResolution` in `tsconfig.json` from `bundler` to `node`

Then I deleted `.next` folder, `node_modules` folder & `package-lock.json` file and reinstalled all my packages

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems identical to [this one](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/58623) reported on the Next.js repository.

Downgrading Next.js to version 13 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue a few days ago.

In dev mode, you should be seeing some critical warnings (in red) on the console. In production mode, you can't see it. They don't create any issues with development, even when you run the local build. But in production, it is treated as an error. You need to fix them in local, and after fixing all such warnings, deploy them again.

To be specific, I can see two types of errors in your application.

1. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sqrt'):
   Be sure an object is not undefined before accessing any of it's properties.One way to do that is to use an `?` operator like `textObject?.property`.
2. Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423; : This is a hydration error. You should be seeing this error in development mode.

Fix these issues and redeploy. Hope this should work.

Comment: I already solved the hydration error locally before deploying it but I still get the error in production mode

Answer (score 0):

the issue is caused by nextjs 14 upgrade, it doesent work well with cyrpto js
this worked for me

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // swcMinify: false,
  transpilePackages: ['crypto-js'],
  
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

by adding this, it fixed by bug check more [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/transpilePackages)